# Creating a map with basemap, filling countries

Tags: python-3.x, csv, matplotlib-basemap

I'm currently working in my final project for my Coding class (my first coding class, so kind of an amateur).

My idea is for a code to search every newspaper in the world for a specific word within the titles (using bs4) and then obtaining a dictionary with the average mentions by country, taking into account the number of newspaper in each country. Afterwards, and this is the part where I'm stuck, I want to put this in a map.

The whole program is already working properly, until the part where I have a CSV with the following form:

```
'Country','Average'
'Afghanistan',10
'Albania',5
'Algeria',0
'Andorra',2
'Antigua and Barbuda',7
'Argentina',0
'Armenia',4
```

Now, I want to create a worldmap where the higher the number, the redder (or any other color) the whole polygon of the country. So far I've found many codes that work well placing points in space, but I haven't found one that "appends" the CSV data presented above and then fills each country accordingly. Below is the part of the code that currently created the worldmap:

```
# Now we proceed with the creation of the map

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))     # We define the size of the map
m = Basemap(resolution='c', # c, l, i, h, f or None
        projection='merc', # Mercator projection
        lat_0=24.20, lon_0=-6.67,   # The center of the mas, so that the whole world is shown without splitting Asia
        llcrnrlon=-180, llcrnrlat= -85,urcrnrlon=180, urcrnrlat=85)     # The coordinates of the whole world

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#46bcec')     # We choose a color for the boundary of the map
m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2',lake_color='#46bcec')      # We choose a color for the land and one for the lakes
m.drawcoastlines()      # We choose to draw the lines of the map
m.readshapefile('Final project\\vincent_map_data-master\\ne_110m_admin_0_countries\\ne_110m_admin_0_countries', 'areas')        # We import the shape file of the whole world

df_poly = pd.DataFrame({            # We define the polygon structure
    'shapes': [Polygon(np.array(shape), True) for shape in m.areas],    
    'area': [area['name'] for area in m.areas_info]     
})

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Oranges')   
pc = PatchCollection(df_poly.shapes, zorder=2)
norm = Normalize()
mapper = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

# We show the map
plt.show(m)
```

I opened the shapefile of the countries and the way to identify the countries is with the variable "sovereignty". There might be some non-sensical things within my code, since I've extracted things from many places. Sorry about that.

If someone could help me out, I would really appreciated. 
Thanks